# React native error AppRegistry not defined?

Tags: ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have been trying import external modules via npm into my react app and after following https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-material-design I am trying to incorporate Material design. I also imported components like Stylesheet from 'react'

Im new to react native and don't understand why Im getting the below error after re running:

[image]

Here is what I have, I am defining App registry as my app name is SkysReact:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card } from 'react-native-material-design';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';

//import AwesomeComponent from "./awesome.js";

//BODY
export default class SkysReact extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<View>
    {this.test()}
    </View>);
  }

  test() {
  console.log("Hello World")
}

animate()
{
  console.log("animate");
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    color: '#333333'
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SkysReact', () => SkysReact);
```

What is wrong? It was running before I added the imports and can't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to import your `AppRegistry`. Adding it to your import statements will clear out your problem

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to import the AppRegistry from react-native.

```
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  Easing,
  ScrollView,
  RefreshControl
} from 'react-native';
```